# GPL v3.0(GNU General Public License v3.0)における表記のやり方

Tags: gpl

### やりたいこと

GitHubで公開されているPythonライブラリを使用したアプリケーションの開発を行っています。このライブラリ自体を改変するのではなく、あくまでimportして使用しています。

このライブラリのライセンスはGPL v3.0となっております。作成したアプリをGitHubで公開したいと考えています。

### 疑問点

作成したアプリケーションをGitHubに公開する際

1. GitHub上でこのライブラリを使用した自分のリポジトリにGPL v3.0のLICENSE.txtを作成する。
2. このライブラリを使用して作成したプログラムの上部に Copyright を記載する。

   ```
   Copyright(c)[year][ライブラリの作者名]
   ```
3. 2.の続きに公開するソフトウェアの簡単な説明文を用意する。

   ```
   例: This program is free software...
   ```

この解釈で問題ないでしょうか？何か足りないことなどありますでしょうか？

また 2. の `[year]` の解釈がいまいち自信がないです。

### 補足

GPL v3.0のライセンスを用いてプログラムを書いたとして、それを公開する際、GPL v3.0のライセンスが必須であると考えているのですが、GitHub上でこのライブラリで検索をかけたところライセンス表記されていないプログラムを拝見しました。
これってまずいですか？それともGitHubに公開する程度ならライセンス表記する必要がないのでしょうか？

### 使用したライブラリ

python-chess
https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess

Comment: GitHub はあくまで場所に過ぎないので、GPL の解釈に関する質問に的を絞った方がよさそうです。

Comment: ご指摘いただきありがとうございます.

Comment: 当該ライブラリを提示していただいた方が話が早いとは思いますが…。そのライブラリは完全なGPL v3.0なのでしょうか？ [リンク例外](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E4%BE%8B%E5%A4%96)が追加されていたりはしないでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。